# Pygame Collision Detection error

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame, random, time

class Game(object):
    def main(self, screen):
        bg = pygame.image.load('data/bg.png')
        house1 = pygame.image.load('data/house1.png')

        playerIdle = pygame.image.load('data/playerIdle.png')
        playerRight = pygame.image.load('data/playerRight.png')
        playerLeft = pygame.image.load('data/playerLeft.png')
        playerUp = pygame.image.load('data/playerUp.png')
        playerX = 0
        playerY = 50

        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        spriteList = []
        gameIsRunning = False

        house1Selected = False


        while 1:
            clock.tick(30)

            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    return
        #delete all sprites on the game(only able to do this in god mode)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d and gameIsRunning == False:
            spriteList = []
        #press 6 to select the house1 image to be placed
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_6 and gameIsRunning == False:
            house1Selected = True
        #spawning the image"house1" at the position of the mouse by pressing space
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE and gameIsRunning == False and house1Selected == True:
            spriteList.append((house1, mouse))
            house1XY = mouse

        #run mode where you cannot build and you move(where I want collision)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_r:
            gameIsRunning = True
        #god mode where you can build and place the house1 image
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_g:
            gameIsRunning = False

        #this is run mode where you can move around and where I want collision
        if(gameIsRunning == True):
            #player Movements
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if playerY <= 0:
                    playerY = 0
                if playerY >= 0:
                    screen.blit(playerUp, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerY = playerY - 2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                PLAYERDOWNLIMIT = 700 - playerIdle.get_height()
                if(playerY >= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                    playerY = PLAYERDOWNLIMIT
                if(playerY <= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                    screen.blit(playerIdle, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerY = playerY + 2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if playerX <= 0:
                    playerX = 0
                if playerX >= 0:
                    screen.blit(playerLeft, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerX = playerX - 2
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT = 1200 - playerIdle.get_width()
                if(playerX >= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                    playerX = PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT
                if(playerX <= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                    screen.blit(playerRight, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerX = playerX + 2

            #collision

            house1Rect = (house1XY, 64, 64)
            playerRect = (playerX, playerY, 32, 32)
            #print(house1Rect)
            #print(playerRect)
            if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect):
                print("collision")

        #this is godmode where you can move around fast n preview where you place images but I don't want collision here
        if(gameIsRunning == False):
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if playerY <= 0:
                    playerY = 0
                if playerY >= 0:
                    screen.blit(playerUp, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerY = playerY - 8
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                PLAYERDOWNLIMIT = 700 - playerIdle.get_height()
                if(playerY >= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                    playerY = PLAYERDOWNLIMIT
                if(playerY <= PLAYERDOWNLIMIT):
                    screen.blit(playerIdle, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerY = playerY + 8
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if playerX <= 0:
                    playerX = 0
                if playerX >= 0:
                    screen.blit(playerLeft, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerX = playerX - 8
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT = 1200 - playerIdle.get_width()
                if(playerX >= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                    playerX = PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT
                if(playerX <= PLAYERRIGHTLIMIT):
                    screen.blit(playerRight, (playerX, playerY))
                    playerX = playerX + 8

        screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))
        #what block are you placing(displays preview)
        if(gameIsRunning == False and house1Selected == True):
            screen.blit(house1, (mouse))

        if(gameIsRunning == True):
            playerXSTR = str(playerX)
            playerYSTR = str(playerY)
            playerXYSTR = ("(" + playerXSTR + ", " + playerYSTR + ")")
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
            playercord = font.render(playerXYSTR, 1, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(playercord, (0, 0))
            runMode = font.render("Run Mode(Cannot build)", 1, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(runMode, (0, 20))
        if(gameIsRunning == False):
            playerXSTR = str(playerX)
            playerYSTR = str(playerY)
            playerXYSTR = ("(" + playerXSTR + ", " + playerYSTR + ")")
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
            playercord = font.render(playerXYSTR, 1, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(playercord, (0, 0))
            godMode = font.render("God Mode(Can build)", 1, (255,255,255))
            screen.blit(godMode, (0, 20))

        for (img, pos) in spriteList:
            screen.blit(img, pos)
        screen.blit(playerIdle, (playerX, playerY))

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
    #screen = pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h))
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 700))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Sandbox')
    Game().main(screen)
```

I'm trying to add collision to my game between the player and the house1 image. At line 330 when the user presses space to spawn the image(house1) at the location of the mouse, it sets the variable house1XY. and at line 393 is where I have the collision. I set house1Rect = (house1XY, 64, 64) and playerRect = (playerX, playerY, 32, 32) and then do an if statement if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect): print("collision") but I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dusty\Desktop\Dropbox\OR Software\Projects\Sandbox Project\game.py", line 512, in <module>
    Game().main(screen)
  File "C:\Users\Dusty\Desktop\Dropbox\OR Software\Projects\Sandbox Project\game.py", line 397, in main
    if playerRect.colliderect(house1Rect):
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'colliderect'
```

I'm really starting to get confused with this collision stuff so if someone could tell me how I could fix this it would be great!

Comment: Many times it's easier for us to find the problem if you boil the code down to be [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In some cases that exercise can even help you find the answer on your own!

Comment: And show the *complete* traceback verbatim, not just the last line of it

Comment: Ok I made the code as minimal as I could(I think) and added the whole traceback

Comment: `playerRect` is a tuple. Tuples don't have the method `colliderect`. Where is `colliderect` defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`playerRect` is a tuple, as defined here:

```
playerRect = (playerX, playerY, 32, 32)
```

You need to make it a `pygame.rect`, using this code:

```
playerRect = pygame.Rect(playerX, playerY, 32, 32)
```

Then you can use the [`colliderect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) method

---

Edit: do the same to `house1Rect`:

```
house1Rect = pygame.Rect(house1XY[0], house1XY[1], 64, 64)
```

Comment: Ok thanks but now when I try to do the house1Rect it says:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dusty\Desktop\Dropbox\OR Software\Projects\Sandbox Project\game.py", line 512, in <module>
    Game().main(screen)
  File "C:\Users\Dusty\Desktop\Dropbox\OR Software\Projects\Sandbox Project\game.py", line 393, in main
    house1Rect = pygame.Rect(house1XY, 64, 64)
TypeError: Argument must be rect style object

Comment: I already changed house1Rect = (house1XY, 64 ,64) to house1Rect = pygame.Rect(house1XY, 64 64) and I got the must have rect style object error.